# How to lock queue for one thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I have a queue that has several producer and consumer threads adding and removing items.  Every once in a while, another thread needs to lock the queue, remove and process every item in the queue, and then release the queue back to the rest of the threads.  How can I keep blocking other threads between successive calls of `queue.get()`.

Comment: Like any shared resource, you will need a mutex `Lock` to prevent concurrent access to it (and all clients must honor it). You should be able to define your own `Queue` subclass that applied such a lock it to all a usual `Queue` instance's methods to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Inspection of the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/queue.py#L42) for the `Queue` class reveals that there is an instance attribute named `mutext` which is a `threading.Lock()` (see line 42). Although no documented, the attribute *is* public (i.e. no leading `_` character) which means you could safely access it. Although its intended use is to make `Queue` objects (automatically) thread-safe, you could manually acquire it at any time to temporarily lock it down (and release it afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to martineau, who has a couple of good approaches to the solution in the comments.  Here is an example class that locks the queue while processing all items in the queue:

```
import queue
from threading import Thread


class PriorityConsumer(Thread):

    def __init__(self, q):
        super(PriorityConsumer, self).__init__()
        self.q = q
    
    def process(self, x):
        pass

    def run(self):
        with self.q.mutex:
            while self.q.queue:
                x = self.q.queue.popleft()
                self.process(x)


q = queue.Queue()
p_consumer = PriorityConsumer(q)
p_consumer.start()
```

Comment: Looks like you "got" the gist what I was trying to convey. Congrats and you're welcome — I'm sure you would do the same for someone else.